# Tableview icon into Navigation bar

Tags: swift

I was wondering, do i have to make a tableview icon as an image, to use it into the navigation bar? I can't find the icon im looking for when i go through Xcode's "System Items". The icon im looking for, is shown on the picture below on the right and left in the navigation bar.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. There is no such default icon provided by XCode. You have to create the icon and then set on left and right barbuttonitem.